# Calculation of inverse matrix in Eigen going wrong

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

Im trying to build a simple input/output matrix (where you can calculate the multiplier effect in a simple economy if demand increases). But for some reason the final result is not adding up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;  

void InputOutput(){
MatrixXf ProdA(5, 5);;
VectorXf Intd(5);
VectorXf Finald(5);
ProdA <<
    10, 20, 0, 0, 5,
    20, 30, 20, 10, 10,
    10, 10, 0, 10, 10,
    10, 40, 20, 5, 5,
    20, 20, 30, 5, 5;

Intd << 55, 40, 20, 30, 10;

Finald << 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;

VectorXf ones(5);
ones << 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;

Finald = ProdA * ones + Intd;

MatrixXf AMatrix = MatrixXf::Zero(ProdA.rows(), ProdA.cols());

AMatrix = ProdA.array() / (Finald.replicate(1, ProdA.cols())).array();
cout << "Here is the Coefficient vector production needed:\n" << AMatrix << endl;

MatrixXf IminA(5, 5);;

IminA = MatrixXf::Identity(AMatrix.rows(), AMatrix.cols()) - AMatrix;

cout << "Here is the matrix of production:\n" << ProdA << endl;
cout << "Here is the vector Internal demand:\n" << Intd << endl;
cout << "Here is the vector Final demand:\n" << Finald << endl;
cout << "Here is the Coefficient vector production needed:\n" << AMatrix << endl;

MatrixXf IminAinv(5, 5);;
IminAinv = IminA.inverse();

cout << "The inverse of CoMatrix - Imatrix is:\n" << IminAinv << endl;

cout << "To check, final demand is:\n" << (IminAinv * Intd) << endl;
```

When I verify if the (I-A)inverse matrix (or IminAinv) is properly calculated it doesn't add up. By multiplying the IminAinv by Internal demand (int), I should get the same Intd. That is if Intd isn't changed. Instead I get a bigger number. Also if I calculate the inverse of the IminA matrix myself, I get something different then eigen.

So something goes wrong in getting the inverse of Identity matrix - Coefficient matrix. But what?

Thanks!

Comment: You should note that using `IminA.inverse();` is dangerous if `IminA` is near singular (ill conditioned). There are other methods that can be safely employed. See the documentation for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
After some more digging into why there are some differences in the final results, I discovered that those "underlying mechanisms" mentioned in Case 2 were, in fact, my own mistake out of inadvertence while entering the matrices' values.

Here follows the original answer with these mistakes taken care of.

---

The actual problem does not lie in the inversion of the *AMatrix* but in a much more subtle detail.
You are using this command to perform the division in the definition of *AMatrix*:

```
AMatrix = ProdA.array() / (Finald.replicate(1, ProdA.cols())).array();
```

But if you check the results of this replicate operation on *Finald* you get:

```
...
cout << "Here is the replicated final demand vector:\n" << (Finald.replicate(1, ProdA.cols())).array() << endl;    
...
>>
Here is the replicated final demand vector:
     90  90  90  90  90
    130 130 130 130 130
     60  60  60  60  60
    110 110 110 110 110
     90  90  90  90  90
```

whereas the correct one should be:

```
90   130    60   110    90
90   130    60   110    90
90   130    60   110    90
90   130    60   110    90
90   130    60   110    90
```

You can transpose the replicated final demand vector like this:

```
MatrixXf Finaldrep(5,5);
Finaldrep = (Finald.replicate(1, ProdA.cols())).array().transpose();
```

and then of course:

```
AMatrix = ProdA.array() / Finaldrep.array();
```

which yields:

```
cout << "Here is the transposed replicated final demand vector:\n" << Finaldrep << endl;
...
>>
Here is the transposed replicated final demand vector:
 90 130  60 110  90
 90 130  60 110  90
 90 130  60 110  90
 90 130  60 110  90
 90 130  60 110  90
```

So, let's see what are the differences in your intermediate and final results in both these cases:

### Case 1

ie Your current approach

```
Here is the Coefficient vector production needed:
 0.111111  0.222222         0         0 0.0555556
 0.153846  0.230769  0.153846 0.0769231 0.0769231
 0.166667  0.166667         0  0.166667  0.166667
0.0909091  0.363636  0.181818 0.0454545 0.0454545
 0.222222  0.222222  0.333333 0.0555556 0.0555556
The determinant of IminA is: 0.420962
The inverse of CoMatrix - Imatrix is:
  1.27266  0.468904  0.131153 0.0688064   0.13951
 0.443909   1.68132  0.377871  0.215443  0.240105
 0.451292  0.628205   1.25318  0.287633  0.312705
 0.404225  0.841827  0.423093   1.20242  0.224877
 0.586957  0.777174  0.586957   0.23913   1.27174
To check, final demand is:
94.8349
 108.09
86.7689
102.689
     95
```

I have also added the determinant of *IminA*

### Case 2

ie using the reversed final demand vector

```
Here is the Coefficient vector production needed:
 0.111111  0.153846         0         0 0.0555556
 0.222222  0.230769  0.333333 0.0909091  0.111111
 0.111111 0.0769231         0 0.0909091  0.111111
 0.111111  0.307692  0.333333 0.0454545 0.0555556
 0.222222  0.153846       0.5 0.0454545 0.0555556
The determinant of IminA is: 0.420962
The inverse of CoMatrix - Imatrix is:
  1.27266  0.324626  0.196729 0.0562962   0.13951
 0.641202   1.68132  0.818721  0.254615  0.346818
 0.300861  0.289941   1.25318  0.156891   0.20847
 0.494053  0.712316   0.77567   1.20242   0.27485
 0.586957  0.538044  0.880435  0.195652   1.27174
To check, final demand is:
 90
130
 60
110
 90
```

<s>Now, I understand that the *Finald check* still does not produce the exact values of the originally defined *Finald*, but I believe that this has something to do with the precision or some other underlying mechanism. (see NOTE)</s>

As a proof of concept here are some results obtained with MATLAB, using the second case (reversed) for the *replicated* Final Demand Vector (denom):

```
>> AMatrixcm = ProdA ./ Finaldfullcm

AMatrixcm =

    0.1111    0.1538         0         0    0.0556
    0.2222    0.2308    0.3333    0.0909    0.1111
    0.1111    0.0769         0    0.0909    0.1111
    0.1111    0.3077    0.3333    0.0455    0.0556
    0.2222    0.1538    0.5000    0.0455    0.0556

>> IminAcm = eye(5) - AMatrixcm

IminAcm =

    0.8889   -0.1538         0         0   -0.0556
   -0.2222    0.7692   -0.3333   -0.0909   -0.1111
   -0.1111   -0.0769    1.0000   -0.0909   -0.1111
   -0.1111   -0.3077   -0.3333    0.9545   -0.0556
   -0.2222   -0.1538   -0.5000   -0.0455    0.9444

>> det(IminAcm)

ans =

    0.4210

>> IminAinvcm = inv(IminAcm)

IminAinvcm =

    1.2727    0.3246    0.1967    0.0563    0.1395
    0.6412    1.6813    0.8187    0.2546    0.3468
    0.3009    0.2899    1.2532    0.1569    0.2085
    0.4941    0.7123    0.7757    1.2024    0.2748
    0.5870    0.5380    0.8804    0.1957    1.2717

>> Finaldcheckcm = IminAinvcm * Intdc

Finaldcheckcm =

   90.0000
  130.0000
   60.0000
  110.0000
   90.0000
```

It is quite clear that the second case results are (almost) identical to the MATLAB ones.

<s>**NOTE:** Here you can see that the MATLAB output is identical to the original *Finald*, however, if you perform the last matrix multiplication (the one in the validation of the Final Demand vector) *by hand*, you will see that in fact both MATLAB and Case 2 versions of *IminAinv* yield the same result as the final output of Case 2, ie [88.9219, 125.728, 59.5037, 105.543, 84.5808].
This is why I think that there is some other mechanism involved in these differences.</s> (See EDIT on top of post)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! edit: nevermind figured it out, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited my answer to include the transpose.